# Keeping lists of Objects, some with, some without inheritance

Tags: java, object-oriented, inheritance

Let's say I have two classes, `Foo` and `ExtendedFoo` where `ExtendedFoo` inherits from `Foo`. `Foo` has a method `.getValue()` which returns a number, `ExtendedFoo` also has `.increaseValue()` which adds to the stored value (Of course, in this example, what they do is completely arbitrary). What I may want to do, is keep track of several objects from each class, and for all `ExtendedFoo` Objects, run `.increaseValue()` and then print out what is returned from `.getValue()` from every Object.

The way I'd do it, would be something like the following:

```
private ArrayList<Foo> foos;
private ArrayList<ExtendedFoo> eFoos;

public static void main(String [] args) {
    foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    eFoos = new ArrayList<ExtendedFoo>();

    // ...
}

public void addFoo(Foo f) {
    foos.add(f);
}

public void addExtendedFoo(ExtendedFoo f) {
    eFoos.add(f);
    foos.add(f);
}

public void updateAndPrint() {
    for(ExtendedFoo ef : eFoos) {
        ef.increaseValue();
    }
    for(Foo f: foos) {
        System.out.println(f.getValue());
    }
}
```

Of course, the obvious problems with this are that the programmer could end up accidentally calling `addFoo()` and `addExtendedFoo()` without realising the real purpose. If I wasn't to include the `foos.add(f)` call to `addExtendedFoo()` then it could go the other way.

What way would you go about this to be as safe as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the reason you inherit ExtendedFoo from Foo is just to reuse the method getValue(), seem like a "smell" to me. You might want to reconsider whether it's a true inheritance relationship. Inheritance should not be abused just to reuse some methods.

In case you still want to go with this design, why don't use instanceof, e.g.:

there's only one list and one way to add both Foo and ExtendedFoo

```
private ArrayList<Foo> foos;

public static void main(String [] args) {
    foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();    

    // ...
}

public void addFoo(Foo f) {
    foos.add(f);
}

public void updateAndPrint() {
    for(Foo f: foos) {
        if(f instanceof ExtendedFoo) {
            f.increaseValue();
        }
    }

    for(Foo f: foos) {
        System.out.println(f.getValue());
    }
}
```